# Weird apache htaccess behavior, not working as its supposed

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

My Apache forwarding works with a strange twist. I'm not sure why this is happening...

```
Redirect 301 /old /new
```

`/old/some_file2.html` forwards me to `/new/some_file2.html`
`/old/some_folder21/` forwards me to `/new/some_folder21`

File and folder structure is different and I just need to forward anything and everything from /old/* to /new

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `RedirectMatch` here for its regex capabilities:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/old /new
```

Or using `mod_rewrite`:

```
RewriteRule ^/?old(/.*)?$ /new? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Same result. /old/XYZ.html forwards me to /new/XYZ.html I don't have same file structure in the new directory and would like to forward all requests (file or folder) from /old/* to /new

Comment: This rule is right, test it in a different browser.

Comment: Did you test in a new browser?

Comment: Yep. Cleared cache, used different browsers, restarted. Still no go. Here is my apache config, if that helps -- http://pastebin.com/TuXz1s6f

Comment: You already have quite a few rule there. Insert this rule: `RewriteRule ^/?old(/.*)?$ /new? [L,NC,R=301]` rule just below `RewriteEngine On` and restart Apache.